# How can I seamlessly update Cyanogenmod by preventing "signature verification failed" error?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, recovery-mode, signature-error

I really like how Cyanogenmod can be updated from the `Settings` menu. After a new update is downloaded, it even asks to if it should reboot to install the new package.

It seems that the update concept is to reboot into recovery (ClockworkMod), verify the update packages signature and **automatically** install it (without a second user confirmation). But the signature verification fails for every Cyanogenmod update so far.

The recovery screen looks approximately like this:

```
Install Untrusted Package?
  THIS CAN NOT BE UNDONE.

- No
- No
- No
- Yes - Install untrusted zip
- No
- No

ClockwordMod Recovery v6.0.2.0
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
E:failed to verify whole-file signature
E:signature verification failed
```

How can I ensure that the signature verification succeeds?

Comment: Do you have ClockWorkMod installed?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question.

Comment: CWM 6.0.2.0 seems outdated. Have you tried updating? http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager

Comment: I remember I had issues with an older CWM when flashing a CM10.2 ROM for my S4.